# Paypal Chained Adaptive Payments

Tags: paypal, chained

I'm a primary receiver of funds on a delayed, chained, adaptive paypal option and only take 10% cut of the transaction.

Let use a simple example. My site allows students to pay experts to write essays on behalf of students(again an example). So teachers are secondary receivers

How my app currently works is that students post a request online to any teacher willing to help.  The teachers bid as per spec. The student then select the teacher.

Once the student select the teacher, the student must deposit funds on Paypal. The funds come to primary receiver (me). But the teacher does not receive anything yet. Until he delivers the essay and the student is happy.

Example the student must deposit $100 to me the primary receiver (when funding the project). Once the teacher has done the job . The students confirms and the teacher then withdraws $90 leaving me with US$10

All the of the above works fine except that when the teacher withdraws $90, US$100 is deducted from my primary account. Leaving me with nothing.

App is on sandbox. Where could be the problem?

Comment: Can you paste your code in your question? Did you integrate Delayed Chained or Instant Chained Payment?

Comment: @amuroray the integration is delayed. I'm also not sure if masspay is supported in my country (South Africa). Paypal confirmed chained is supported.Code too long to paste.

Comment: any website for test? The best is to file a ticket to their technical team. https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask/session/L3RpbWUvMTQ5NjU3MDUwMy9zaWQvZlVUSlhUSkZidzZXbW5YM2pXdE4xUUJWS2VsakJMd1Q3WmltNkxXanRUWm84cTBnRnowOHRkQjVsUDR6WDdaMEFmYXJhMlRfOFkxZVZZUVBYbGdya3hTUnJUR2taNUdvaFUxeHgyTklNMlRmRjIwOFVoTjhpTkRBJTIxJTIx

Answer (score 0):

The cause may somehow be within your PAY API request. Could you please share them here so that we could help take a look.

Comment: the code is longer than allowed to paste here. Is there an alternative way to share?